# How can I send crash reports from Android using Google Analytics API v2

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I am having troubles (and a lot of frustration) trying to set up a working GoogleAnalytics environment on my Android native app. Mainly it seems to me that the documentation is rather incomplete, which is not a problem as long as it's working. But it's not, in my case.

I have created a profile on GoogleAnalytics. I can see it's working fine in two manners:

- In the logs, I can see which URL the app is using to report basic activity usage
- On the GoogleAnalytics dashboard / Real-time / Overview I can see that my use of the app is reported.

However, I can't see any crash coming up whatever the alternative listed on [GoogleAnalytics' documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v2/exceptions) I'm using.

Are crash reports also supposed to come with a 24h delay?

Setting

```
<bool name="ga_reportUncaughtExceptions">true</bool>
```

, when a crash happens (explicitely throwing a *new RuntimeException("TestGoogleAnalytics")*), i can see in the logs:

```
I/GAV2    (31358): Thread[main,5,main]: Tracking Exception: TestGoogleAnalytics
W/GAV2    (31358): Thread[main,5,main]: dispatch call queued.  Need to call GAServiceManager.getInstance().initialize().
I/GAV2    (31358): Thread[main,5,main]: Passing exception to original handler.
```

And I'm wondering if the warning hints anything about something I've missed to initialize.

I haven't been able to find much information about this

```
GAServiceManager.getInstance().initialize()
```

Any help appreciated :)

Comment: maybe post some gode. did you set `<bool name="ga_reportUncaughtExceptions">true</bool>` in your `analytics.xml` file?

Comment: Yes, I've tried all alternatives listed at https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v2/exceptions 
ga_reportUncaughtExceptions is one of them. 
The three log lines I've pasted above come only when I set ga_reportUncaughtExceptions to true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I finally got my reports the day after. Somehow "GAV2" is printing out a lot of errors and warnings that don't seem to affect statistics and crash reports.

Comment: Google analytics v2 can statistics native cash reports?

Comment: I haven't looked much more into that issue since I now use another component to report crashes.

Comment: You mean Exception/crash report are not available directly? I mean, we have to wait 24 hours or so to see exception in  'Crashes and Exceptions'?

Comment: I don't know. This question is almost two years old, obviously the API has changed a lot since then. And I am using other tools for error reporting (Mint Splunk Express, former BugSense if you ask)